# Python Tkinter: Binding Same Key Twice?

Tags: python, function, binding, tkinter, key

Is there a way to bind the same key to and object in Tkinter? Here's my situation.

I am using a Multi List Box Class, but it already has Button 1 bound with a function that selects the same row in each of the other listbox's. Now i want to add another function to Button 1 in my class while using a copy of the multi list box class. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just make a wrapper for the two functions and make that function the function your binding calls:

```
def key_press_wrapper():
    your_function1()
    your_function2()
```

It should be as easy as that.

for an example of it on the return key:

```
from Tkinter import *

def key_press_wrapper():
    your_function1()
    your_function2()
root=Tk()
root.bind('<Return>',key_press_wrapper)
```

Comment: Haha i don't know why i didn't think of this. Thank you a lot i have been hung up on this all day.